# Javascript doesn't bind with customer registration form validation in magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I am insert custom confirm email field but validation.js is not working. I use magento 1.9.2.3, and am working with registration.phtml file. How can I create a new folder in persistent for validation?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:126:"Invalid method Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register::addJs(Array
(
    [0] => persistent/customer/form/js/email/validation.js
)
)";i:1;s:1902:"#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('addJs', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register->addJs('persistent/cust...')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AccountController.php(252): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->createAction()
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('create')
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-Project\MYDEMO\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}";s:3:"url";s:45:"/Magento-Project/MYDEMO/customer/account/create/";s:11:"script_name";s:30:"/Magento-Project/MYDEMO/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adding Confirm E-mail Address Field in Magento Frontend Forms::**

1. Search following code in  /js/prototype/validation.js

   `return !(pass.length < 7);     }],`

after this code Add below code :

```
['validate-cemail', 'Please make sure your emails match.', function(v) {
var conf = $$('.validate-cemail')[0];
var pass = false;
if ($('email')) {
pass = $('email');
}
var emailElements = $$('.validate-email');
for (var i = 0; i < emailElements.size(); i++) {
var emailElement = emailElements[i];
if (emailElement.up('form').id == conf.up('form').id) {
pass = emailElement;
}
}
if ($$('.validate-admin-email').size()) {
pass = $$('.validate-admin-email')[0];
}
return (pass.value == conf.value);
}],
```

2. Then In phtml page you have to add this

   `<input type="text" name="confirm_email" id="confirm_email_address" class="input-text required-entry validate-cemail"/>`